# get children div id of li on double click using AngularJS

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working with Angular JS in my current project. I need to get id of div tag which is nested in li tag on double click of li tag. see below code.

I try children logic but it is not working.

```
        var mainMod = angular.module('chartApp', []);
        mainMod.controller('chartAppController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            var flag = 1;
            $scope.doubleClick = function (event) {
                var chId = $(this).children('div.panel.panel-primary').children('div.panel-body.chartBody').children('div').attr('id');
                alert(chId);
            }
             }
        }])
```

below is code structure.

```
<div class="container-fluid" data-ng-app="chartApp" data-ng-controller="chartAppController">
            <ul id="dashboard">
                @foreach (var chart in chartCollection)
                {
                    <li ng-dblclick="doubleClick($event)">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading chartTileHeader">
                                <span class="chartTitle">@chart.Title</span>
                                <div class="chartIcon">
                                    <i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body chartBody">
                                <div id=@chart.Id>
                                .....
                                </div>  
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

var chId = $(event.currentTarget).find('div.panel-body.chartBody > div').attr('id')

Comment: This solution is working fine with jquery. but i have to use angularjs so this is not working in angularjs

Comment: I updated my answer.  You are sending in the event object, use it's target property to access the element clicked.

Comment: I also tried event.target but it depends upon where i double click. means my <li> tag contains two <div> tag if i double click on first div event.target will return first div. but i want <li> as a parent and find child from it.

Comment: Hmmm ok.  Try event.currentTarget instead of event.target

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this:

**event.target** is working for particular element in < li > tag.

```
 var chId = $(event.target).find('div.panel-body.chartBody > div').attr('id')
```

but if you want to get child hierarchy of < li > tag on double click then you should use **event.currentTarget**

```
var mainMod = angular.module('chartApp', []);
    mainMod.controller('chartAppController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        var flag = 1;
        $scope.doubleClick = function (event) {
            var chId = $(event.currentTarget).find('div.panel-body.chartBody > div').attr('id');
            alert(chId);
        }
         }
    }])
```

Answer (score 0):

use **[find](https://api.jquery.com/find/)** selector to find particular element

```
$(this).find('div.panel-body.chartBody div').map(function(){
       return this.id;
  }).get();
```

if you have single div

```
$(this).find('div.panel-body.chartBody > div').attr('id')
```

Comment: I debug the code but $(this) is not working in angularjs.
i tried it in jquery it working fine in jquery but i have to use angularjs